# Edit a boolean value on click on a button at customised table view cell

Tags: iphone

i have a table view with customized cell. each cell contains a button that is added a contentView addSubview. Now I want to update a Boolean value in database table  regarding to row of which button is clicked.

How should I get the index of the row whose button is clicked as when you click on the button it does not select the row on which the button  exist .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could set the tag of the UIButton as the row of your tableView ?

```
[ cell setTag:<#(NSInteger)#> ];
```

Then when a tap occured, you get the tag (from the sender you cast to a UIButton*), transform it in NSInteger and can change the bool in your database ^^

If you have more than One section, you could trick like doing tag = section * 100 + row.

Good Luck !

Comment: adding tag on cell is not helpfull