# UISwitch and UIButton in UITableViewCell, how to ident them

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uibutton, uiswitch

I've got a little problem in my UITableViewCell.
Each Custom Cell have an UISwitch and an UIButton. And when the user change the value of the UISwitch i would like to set the button.hidden property to YES.

I can find which UISwitch was clicked with this method:

```
- (IBAction)closeHour:(id)sender {

     UISwitch  *senderSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
     UITableViewCell *switchCell = (UITableViewCell *)[senderSwitch superview];
     NSUInteger buttonRow = [[resas indexPathForCell:switchCell] row];
     NSLog("%d", buttonRow);
}
```

This work perfectly, but i don't know how to get the UIButton at the same index (indexPath.row) to set his hidden property. I thought about setting a tag in each UIButton but i'm not very friendly with those.

There is how my Cell was created, if someone can tell me if i am doing some crap here it could be very nice:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  { 
     static NSString   *cellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
     static NSString   *cellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

     if ([typeOfData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == @"hour") {
         TimeCell   *cell = (TimeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];

      if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[[TimeCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier1] autorelease];
          UISwitch *isOpen = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 7, 0, 0)];

          if ([self openOrCloseHour:[[[finalData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] substringToIndex:2] intValue]])
              isOpen.on = YES;
          else {
              isOpen.on = NO;
              [isOpen addTarget:self action:@selector(closeHour:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
              [cell addSubview:isOpen];
              [isOpen release];
              UIButton   *add = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
              add.frame = CGRectMake(400, 3, 170, 40);
              [add addTarget:self action:@selector(addResa:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
              [cell addSubview:add];
          }
      }
      [cell.time setText:[finalData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      return cell;
   }
   else 
   {
         ResaCell   *cell = (ResaCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];

         if (cell == nil) {
             cell = [[[ResaCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier2] autorelease];
             [cell.isConfirm setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"confirm.png"]];
             [cell.nom  setText:[finalData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
             [cell.prenom  setText:[finalData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
             [cell.arrive  setText:[finalData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
         }

         return cell;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

For information I have got two type of cell. The problem is on TimeCell.

Is anybody have the solution ?

Comment: Hello. Take a look at my last response ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888771/edit-a-boolean-value-on-click-on-a-buton-at-customised-table-view-cell ). Your problem is in the same way. But you need in addition to get a View with viewWithTag: ^^ Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i can't do that. The method is call by the UISwitch not the UIButton so, the sender is the UISwitch and there is no way to ident the UIButton. Maybe i'm wrong anyway i failed on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cellForRow :

```
isOpen.tag = 2000+indexPath.row;
add.tag = 4000+indexPath.row;
```

To get the UIButton in the closeHour IBACtion make :

```
int tagButton = senderSwitch.tag-2000+4000;
button = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:tagButton];
```

Comment: hallelujah !!! it work perfectly !!! Thanks a lot. But why i have to add 2000 or 4000 ?

Comment: You can replace them with "bigs" numbers you want !